# I can't check in an existing project to VisualStudio.com

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, azure-devops

I have Visual Studio Express 2012 installed which is linked to my VisualStudio.com account, I created a new project but I didn't tick the

> Add to source control

option as I was intending it to be a throwaway project. However, I now want to keep it so I am trying to add it to source control after the fact.

I've tried both adding the project to source control when the project is open and moving the files from the "Excluded Changes" section of the Pending Changes window. In both cases I get the following error:

> TF10169: Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/RadioButtonTest.  Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one.

My default collection is mapped to E:\Chris\projects and the project I'm trying to add is directly in that folder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had exactly the same happen - mucked about a bit and got it working by adding a project of the same name to my VS Online page.

Try this:

1. Open your web browser to your visualstudio.com homepage
2. Under "Recent projects & teams"
3. Hit "New"
4. Use your "RadioButtonTest" as the project name and go through the
   creation flow
5. Check in from VS

Comment: This is the first thing everyone will try to do with this product. Why didn't Microsoft test this case? Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I found a much simpler way to add the Project to Source Control for Visual Studio 12. I selected the project, go to the "FILE" menu, selected "Source Control", where you may see an option to "add this project to source control".

If you don't see that option, though I think you will; you can select "Advance" then "Change Source Control". In that dialog box you will see all the projects bound to the solution. Select the project you want to add to source control, and choose "unbind" then "ok". (it will throw a warning that some files were already in source-control, select "ignore all") Now your project is unbound, right click on the project name, the option to "add this to source control", and voila! Now you're running with petrol!

Comment: This works for me. It's when you already had your solution added to source control then you could not add your newly created projects to source control.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because there isn't a "team project" for the solution but there more than likely is a collection which isn't the same thing.

The above answers helped me figure it out but all I had to do was create a new team project from the instructions on MS's website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhedaeb2(v=vs.90).aspx and then I was able to add solution to source control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are getting this error but here is another approach you could take.

- Create a new project with the same name and check the "Add to Source Control" project.
- Commit the initial version and close the project in Visual Studio
- Copy the contents of the real project over the newly created project
- Re-open in Visual Studio and let it detect the new changes
- Commit the new changes to SCC

This is a round about way of getting an existing project into source code control.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Add Solution to Source Control".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I tried to create a new TFS project folder (rather than a "team project") at the root.  After trying everything suggested above, I did the following:

1. copied my code to another folder
2. did an "undo" on all pending changes (making sure that the only changes included were the ones for the project at hand)
3. deleted the filesystem folder
4. created a "team project" in TFS Team Explorer (this wizard automatically creates a folder at the root and checks in the changeset)
5. copied my source code back to a folder with the same name as the team project
6. opened the solution in VS
7. right-clicked the solution and clicked "add solution to source control"
8. checked in...success at last!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I went to check in a project, I had created the solution in a new team folder that was not in TFS and fixed it by doing the following:

1. Go to Team Explorer
2. Click the drop-down arrow to the right of Home
3. Click Projects and My Teams
4. Click New Team Project...

Add a team project with the same name as the new project folder.